# Are there any actions to take after rescuing questions?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, vote-to-close

During a close question review, I tried to salvage: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027402/what-ways-are-there-to-support-multiple-languages-for-an-asp-net-website/13029707#13029707)

Hopefully the edit was appropriate and turned it into a real enough question without changing too much of the question.

However, while I was editing, the question accumulated 4 close votes.

Apart from answering it, is there anything else that I should do to/for this question as part of the rescue effort?

Comment: Now that it has closed, you could cast a reopen vote...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question gets closed, you can vote to re-open it (if you have enough reputation to do it), and give the question the attention of who can vote to re-open it; for example, you could open a question on the meta site for asking to re-open the question, or asking in which way the question could be made acceptable.

Comment: Now that there's a re-open queue you shouldn't need to post on meta to get attention, the queue will take care of that.

Comment: If you want to know if the question still needs to be improved, a question on the meta site could help. The same is true if you really think the question should be re-opened, and you want to expose your reasons for doing so.